# How to activate the hr schema in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am learning PL/SQL and am using SQL Developer cause I created many users with hr schema. But when a user logs in to SQL Developer give an error like the users is invalid. but When I use the system user, it works perfectly but without hr schema.

So:

- How can I activate the hr schema in system user **or**
- How can I make a user for use in SQL developer.

I am using Oracle 11g express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this should even be an answer since the question is kind of light on concrete details, but you need to grant the appropriate privileges on the database to the new users for them to be usable.

For example you need to grant "create session" for the user to be able to connect and appropriate access to the tables the users should have access to.

Then the users have the correct privileges, you should be fine using SQL developer.

You can find a sample that may help you setting up a user correctly over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/admusers.htm#i1006856) but setting up permissions on the database is a bit dependent on how you want the security to work (ie read-only, stored procedures, access to certain tables restricted...)

Comment: yeah I know that but how can I do it in oracle 11g.can you give a link references to the topic.

Comment: Added an URL how to create and set up a basic user to the answer.

Comment: ok thanks I got this searching in the net I hope to this help to any body else 
this is how to activated the ht schema by comand line 
**alter user hr account unlock identified by pass**

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson, Awesome explanation.

Answer (score 16):

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

Then, enter this command

CONNECT HR/HR

Comment: That's really the answer. Also could refer to [official oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm) on that

Answer (score 6):

This may help

> ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
>
> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to hr;
>
> ALTER USER oe IDENTIFIED BY OE ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
>
> GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to OE;

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER USER hr IDENTIFIED BY hr ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE to hr;
CONNECT HR/hr;
Password : hr
```